# Closure with respect to a topological basis

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So in finding the closure of any subset $\mathbb{Z}$, we have the problem:

> Given the topological base $\bigl\{[-n,n]:n>0\bigr\}$, find the closure with respect to this topological basis.

I have the solution, but the problem is I do not understand this solution in my notes and it goes:

> $k$ will have the closure of $B$ iff $|k| \le n \implies B\cap[-n,n] \ne \varnothing$, hence the closure of $B = [-a,a]$, where $a$ is the maximum of the absolute values of the numbers in $B$.

Note that $[m,n]=\{k\in \mathbb{Z}: m \le k \le n\}$.

I generally do not get this solution at all. Can anyone help me understand it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is incorrect. My first hint was this: "the maximum of the absolute values of $B$." Since $B$ may be an infinite subset of $\Bbb Z,$ such maximum may not exist!

The open sets in the given topology turn out to be $\emptyset,$ $\Bbb Z,$ and the elements of the given basis. Consequently, the *closed* sets with respect to the given topology are $\Bbb Z,$ $\emptyset,$ and the sets of the form $(-\infty,-n-1]\cup[n+1,\infty)$ for positive integers $n.$

Now, take any $B\subseteq\Bbb Z.$ If $B\cap\{-1,0,1\}\neq\emptyset,$ then the closure of $B$ is $\Bbb Z.$ If $B=\emptyset,$ then the closure of $B$ is $\emptyset.$ Suppose, instead, that $B$ is non-empty, and that $|k|>1$ for all $k\in B.$ Take $a=\min\bigl\{|k|:k\in B\bigr\},$ and let $C=(-\infty,-a]\cup[a,\infty).$ I claim that $C$ is the desired closure of $B,$ which is readily shown, as $C$ is closed with respect to the given topology, and as $B\subseteq C.$

Comment: Thank you I will try to understand this solution. Now I am worried about the next question is well which might also have been wrong since you are telling me this one is wrong. The next example was finding the closure of any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $\{2^n\mathbb{Z}: n\in Z\},$ and the answer was $\mathbb{N}-2^{a+1}\mathbb{N}$ the closure of $B.$

Comment: Why is the intersection with the $\emptyset$ when $B=\emptyset, \ne \emptyset?$

Comment: Well, how is closure defined for you?

Comment: Closure is defined as the set which contains all the limit points of the set say $A.$

Comment: That isn't quite right. A set is *closed* if it contains all of its limit points. Given a set $A,$ the set of limit points of $A$ is often called the *derived set* of $A,$ and often denoted as $A'$. The *closure* of $A$ is $A\cup A'.$

Comment: Your next question would be better addressed as a separate Question on the site. Also, having thought about it, I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for the kind help, yes I will actually go and ponder on it more.

Comment: Let ms know if you have any further questions about this problem.

Comment: Yes, Thank you !!